# Not run application from Mono in Ubuntu

Tags: winforms, ubuntu, visual-studio-2010, mono

I used `Visual Studio 2010` + `Mono 2.4` Profile.

Create simply `WinForms` application.

I need it to run on `Ubuntu`.

**Ubuntu Crash Error Report:**

```
(Client.exe:1963) WARNING: The following assembly referenced from
  /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
  could not be loaded:
  Assembly: Accessibility (assemblyref_index=8)
  Version: 2.0.0.0
  Public Key: b03f5f7f11d50a3a

  The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache,
  a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or
  in the location of the executing assembly
  (/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/).

(Client.exe:1963) WARNING: Could not load file or assembly
  'Accessibility, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

(Client.exe:1963) WARNING: The class System.Windows.Forms.Control
  could not be loaded, used in
  System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0,
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

(Client.exe:1963) WARNING: The class System.Windows.Forms.Control
  could not be loaded, used in
  System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0,
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

(Client.exe:1963) WARNING: The class System.Windows.Forms.Control
  could not be loaded, used in
  System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0,
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: A type load
exception has occurred.
```

**I fixed a bug that?**

```
simply@simply-VirtualBox:~/Загрузки$
dpkg --get-selections | grep mono

libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil install

libmono-addins0.2-cil install

libmono-cairo2.0-cil install

libmono-corlib2.0-cil install

libmono-i18n-west2.0-cil install

libmono-management2.0-cil install

libmono-posix2.0-cil install

libmono-security2.0-cil install

libmono-sharpzip2.84-cil install

libmono-system2.0-cil install

libmono-winforms2.0-cil install

mono-2.0-gac install

mono-csharp-shell install

mono-gac install

mono-gmcs install

mono-runtime install

ubuntu-mono install
```

Comment: What a mistake to take off?
and how to get rid of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sudo apt-get -f install
>   libmono-accessibility2.0-cil

Answer (score 0):

You may hook the unhandled exception handler, and see what is the exception detail of that System.TypeLoadException.